# How to gsub using patterns

Tags: r, string, dataframe, gsub

I have a list X with element names like this

`down_PK56c-t_S5_L001.clones_IGH`

I want to rename the elements to be something like this

`PK56c-t`

how can I do it using gsub?
I tried this and it did not work :/

`gsub(".*[down_]([^.]+)[.].*", "\\1", "down_PK56c-t_S5_L001.clones_IGH")`

thanks a lot

Comment: This gets what you want `gsub("down_([^_]+)_.*", "\\1", "down_PK56c-t_S5_L001.clones_IGH")`.  It assumes that you want to get what's between the two underscore characters that come after "down"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `sub` here like

```r
sub(".*down_([^_]+).*", "\\1", text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7rKLnS/1).

*Details*:

- `.*` - any zero or more chars as possible
- `down_` - a literal string
- `([^_]+)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this group text): one or more chars other than an underscore
- `.*` - any zero or more chars as possible

Answer (score 1):

We can also use an `extract` strategy with a look behind:

```
library(stringr)

string <- "down_PK56c-t_S5_L001.clones_IGH"
str_extract(string, pattern = "(?<=down_)[^_]+")

[1] "PK56c-t"
```